# Echo all API Settings sections?

Tags: settings-api

Is there a WordPress function displaying all sections registered with [add_settings_section()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section)?

I was thinking about SQL query maybe, but have absolutely no idea how and where these are stored, couldn't find them in my database.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood... - if you are after a list of section slugs see Chip's answer. If you actually just want to output the contents of all sections registered to a page see mine. The sections aren't stored in the database.

Comment: Yes, you did, I wanted to list all sections within the whole theme, not only certain pages. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your pages are available/registered on every admin page UI request, so summing them up and then outputting them with the public API like @StephenHarris has shown is how it should be done.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to output *pages*. I think you're misreading the question, @kaiser.

Comment: @Wordpressor - mind me asking what you want this for? I can't think of a scenario where you might need it and there isn't a public API alternative...

Comment: @ChipBennett See my answer/example - It would have exceeded the space of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$wp_settings_sections` global](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1023). It returns an array of settings sections.

Comment: You shouldn't rely code on internal globals.

Comment: What is wrong with using the global here, when *the data contained by the global is **exactly** what the OP wants*?

Comment: That internal globals can change content & behavior from version to version. Also: If it's about the `$page`, then you'll get the page as return value when registering the page. That means that you get it on every admin-UI request and can therefore reuse it without a problem. Summing different pages isn't a problem either.

Comment: What's changing with `$wp_settings_sections`? The OP wants a *list of registered settings*, which is only and always what `$wp_settings_sections` contains.

Comment: Just an example (like it's valid for every internal global): The name could change.

Comment: +1, this gives an array of registered sections at that particular time, as asked for.

Comment: -1, this gives the desired result in a bad way.

Comment: @grok you're apparently not reading the question correctly, too. He wants a *list of registered settings sections*, **NOT** to output the *content* of those sections.

Answer (score 3):

This outputs all the sections registered to the page passed in the argument:

```
do_settings_sections($page)
```

See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_sections).

Comment: public API solution always gets +1

Comment: @kaiser: except, that's not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score -2):

### Use the core API

A) If you read the Codex about …

[`add_settings_section( $id, $title, $callback, $page );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section)

… then you'll find the `@param $page`.

B) This is the menu page that you registered using …

[`add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page)

C) This is used on every admin-UI request. If it wouldn't then stuff like the screen dependend hooks wouldn't work:

`$example = "admin_print_styles-{$screen}";`

### Solution

Sum up all your pages when registering them:

```
// Example:
$pages[] = add_menu/submenu_page/theme/etc_page( ... );
foreach( $pages as $page )
    do_settings_sections( $page );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, which is: "*Is there a WordPress function displaying **all sections registered** with `add_settings_section()`?*" The OP wants *the names of registered settings sections*, not *settings pages*.

Comment: This shows "_how to get all sections that were registered. By the one who writes the code_". Everything else would likely crash in the first second. If the OP really wants to crash stuff than the right answer would be "_Leave it!_" and nothing else.

Comment: Based on the OP's question, and clarifying comment, he wants to display a *list of sections*, **not** output the *content* of those sections.

Comment: "_within the whole theme_". So yes, only those that he registered himself. On the other hand: Yes, there's no public API function to far to get only the _names_. On the third hand (if you got that many): As he registered them himself, he could also drop the names in a custom global or write a custom personal API function to retrieve them. Trying to rely on core code for such a tasks is nonsense in my opinion. The sense of the Q seems to want to hide away from me.

Comment: @ChipBennett Btw: This wasn't meant to be the answer. It was meant as an explanation _to you only_ as you can read in the comments above.